# JS & Angular: Date object is "out of date"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've seen many things in JS, but this one haunts me in my dreams. Unfortunately my environment is pretty complex. But here is what I think is important (if you miss anything please ask):

- We're using Angular around 1.4.3
- I a lot of directives, in this case three (written with `controllerAs` syntax, so no `$scope` or `$whatever` in game)
- The directives are using a shared `model` injected via directive like `<myDirective model="base.model">`

My problem is a difference between what's actually in the model and what I get when I access that model directly. Reduced to the important thing, this happens:

```
console.log( vm.model )
  [listing all the stuff until:]

  startDate: Fri May 13 2016 15:10:19 GMT+0200

console.log( vm.model.startDate )

  Thu May 12 2016 15:10:19 GMT+0200
```

Basically the date is always correct when looking at the first one ( `log(vm.model)`) and it's wrong when accessing the `vm.model.startDate` directly (I checked that, it's not ony a wrong `toString` output, the date is actually out of date. When now changing the date via the `dateTimePicker` I use the model will have the right value again and when accessing the variable directly it will be `Fri May 13 2016 15:10:19 GMT+0200`. To be clear: When accessing the model variable directly I always get the **last** valid value. The values are interpreted after a ng-change was fired. I'd guess some parallel/race condition stuff is going on, but how can I get 2 different things in 2 lines (no matter in which order by the way, object always right, direct access/`toString` always wrong).

Do you have any idea what's possibly going on?